# How to split an ArrayList<E> into ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm pretty new to java and trying to create an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` from `ArrayList<Integer>` (splitting 28800 data points into pieces of 300).

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> createListOfArrays(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int arrayInt = list.get(i);
        temp.add(arrayInt);

        if (temp.size() % 300 == 0) {
            listOfArrays.add(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
    }

    return listOfArrays;    

    System.out.println(listOfArrays.size());
    System.out.println(listOfArrays.get(0).size());
}
```

My print statements give me the right size of 96 `ArrayLists` but they are all empty. If I remove `temp.clear()` they all consist of 28800 `Integers`.

I need `96 * 300` different `ArrayLists` in an `Arraylist`.

Comment: You are only working on one instance of an `ArrayList` for your `temp` variable. Instead of calling `temp.clear()` you should be doing `temp = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: don't use clear because you are saving a reference of temp in arraylist and then clearing it in loop. In loop initialize temp = new ArrayList<Integer> and then add values to it. This will create a new instance of temp every time and store values in listOfArrays solving your issue

Comment: The `System.out` lines are unreachable, meaning this code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Integer arrayInt = list.get(i);
    temp.add(arrayInt);

    if (temp.size() % 300 == 0) {
        listOfArrays.add(temp);
        temp = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

> Dont use primitive `int` while retrieving element from list. Because it will unnecessarily cause `unboxing` and then `autoboxing` again.
>
> Rather than relying on `list.size() % 300 == 0`, You should change your logic also.

You can even use `arraylist` method `subList`.

Comment: This would miss the last batch from `listOfArrays` unless `list.size() % 300 == 0`.

Comment: Yes true, but data size given is `28800` and `list.size() % 300 == 0`

Comment: Which `Collections` class are you referring to? `java.util.Collections` doesn't have a method `subList`. And relying on the input size being an exact multiple of 300 isn't very robust.

Comment: @AndyTurner. I know its not robust , my intention was not to provide full proof solution but to indicate the error in code. So where ever possible logically I used original code. And yup sorry for what I had mentioned earlier in confusion. Anyway i edited it now. Anyway edited as per your suggestion also.

Answer (score 1):

They are empty because you are clearing the list immediately after you add it - adding `temp` to `listOfArrays` doesn't copy it. You are just adding the same list to `listOfArrays` lots of times.

You can do this much more easily using `List.subList` to extract 300-element blocks from list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 300) {
  // Extract a view of this block of (up to) 300 elements.
  List<E> subList = list.subList(i, Math.min(i+300, list.size()));
  // Copy it into a new list since we require an ArrayList to add
  // to `listOfArrays`.
  ArrayList<E> copy = new ArrayList<>(subList);
  // Put it into the result.
  listOfArrays.add(copy);
}
```

Comment: It’s not clear from the question whether the copying step is actually necessary. Maybe, adding the sublists directly to the result list is sufficient.

Comment: @Holger: I think copying is necessary - just not for the reason I wrote - `ArrayList.subList` doesn't return an `ArrayList`, and the return type of the method is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Edited.

Comment: Yeah, I missed this requirement before the edit. However, it’s still possible that this is not a real requirement but that the questioner doesn’t know about the advantages of using `List<List<…>>` instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList<…>>`; you got my upvote anyway as using `subList` is pushing him into the right direction…

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> createListOfArrays(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     int arrayInt = list.get(i);
     temp.add(arrayInt);

     if (i % 300 == 0) {
         listOfArrays.add(temp);
         //assigning new ArrayList object in temp
         temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     }

 }
 //adding last batch of temp to listOfArrays
 if(temp.size()>0){
         listOfArrays.add(temp);
  }

 return listOfArrays;    

 System.out.println(listOfArrays.size());
 System.out.println(listOfArrays.get(0).size());
 }
```

This should do the trick for you. Explanation provided in comments above.

Comment: This would miss the last batch from listOfArrays unless `list.size() % 300 == 0`.

Comment: yeah ... agreed @AndyTurner ... thanks for pointing that out.